# Hotmail rejects all server mails

Tags: email, spam, hotmail

Mails send from my server never arrive at hotmail accounts, even spam shows nothing.
I tested my mails at mail-tester.com and auth-results@verifier.port25.com, both got the best score. I host at digital ocean with cPanel with my own nameservers, my server logs don't report any problems and shows that the mails are delivered successfully.

Things I have checked/tried:

- SPF records
- Sender-ID
- PTR records
- DKIM signature
- I signed in for the Junk Mail Reporting Program
- I checked the blocked sender list in outlook
- Checked all black lists

I don't have problems with any other major mailproviders like Gmail except Hotmail.
I really don't know what to do anymore..

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this issue, apparently Microsoft blocks random IP addresses. For the people who are also having trouble with this issue, I recommend using Mandrill.